# how to join multiple telegram group with telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I want to join multiple groups with telethon python but I can't
I can only able to join one group at a time anyone knows how to join multiple groups at the same time

```
with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.channels.JoinChannelRequest(
        channel='username'
    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop in order to loop and join the groups one by one.
Your code can be as such:

```
groups = ['group_1', 'group_2']
with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    for group in groups:
        result = client(functions.channels.JoinChannelRequest(
            channel=group
        ))
        time.sleep(60) # or await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

Make sure to have some sort of a delay too or you'll get your account suspended or banned.